# JQUERY change attr after sound load

Tags: jquery, audio, playback

I have a problem with mobile device.
After click event start sound and animation gif, but on mobile the sound start after animation, because maybe heavier.
How can I do?

```
var click = function(){
    $('.audio')[0].play();
    $('.change').attr('src', "animation.gif");

    setTimeout(function () {
    $('.change').attr('src', "stop.png");
    }, 600);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$(".audio").on("play", function (e) {
   $('.change').attr('src', "animation.gif");
   setTimeout(function () {
       $('.change').attr('src', "stop.png");
   }, 600);
});
```

Comment: is the event triggered?

Comment: add an alert before the animation

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39097/discussion-between-giovanni-and-dvir)